# Why is my serial read application not responding?

Tags: c++, mfc, serial-port

I have written the following serial read function that is supposed to wait for the `EV_RXCHAR` event to be raised, after which it should read in a continuous loop

```
void CGCUGUIDlg::OnStartcom() 
{
    m_hComm = ::CreateFile(Com, //String that contains COM port name
            GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,                          
            0,               
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            0
            );

    fnCommState();
    DCB dcb = {0};
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

    Status = GetCommState(m_hComm, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    SetCommState(m_hComm, &dcb);

    OVERLAPPED o;
    BOOL fSuccess;
    DWORD dwEvtMask;
    DWORD NoBytesRead;
    BYTE abBuffer[100];

    fSuccess = SetCommMask(m_hComm,EV_RXCHAR);

    if(!fSuccess)
    {
        MessageBox("SetCommMask failed with error %s",LPCTSTR(GetLastError()));
        return;
    }

    o.hEvent = CreateFile(0,0,0,NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);

    o.Internal = 0;
    o.InternalHigh = 0;
    o.Offset = 0;
    o.OffsetHigh = 0;

    assert(o.hEvent);

    for(;;)
    {
        if(WaitCommEvent(m_hComm,&dwEvtMask,&o)) //if 1
        {
            if(dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) //if 2
            {
                do
                {
                    ReadFile(m_hComm,&abBuffer,sizeof(abBuffer),&NoBytesRead,&o);
                    data.Append(LPCTSTR(abBuffer),NoBytesRead);
                }//do
                while(NoBytesRead>0);
                if((data.GetAt(1)==10)&& data.GetLength() == 100) //if 3, EDIT 1
                {
                    result = data;
                    this->SetDlgItemText(IDC_RXRAW,LPCTSTR(result));
                    this->UpdateDate(false); //EDIT 2
                }//if 3
            }//if 2
        }//if 1
        Sleep(40);
    }//for


}
```

SOME DETAILS:

1 The application receives 100 bytes every 60 milliseconds, with no gap between bytes in those 100 bytes.

2 The header bytes are specified so I am doing a check for this and the message size.

3 Both `data` and `result` are `CString` variables.

4 Although I did not copy the code outright, I did base my code heavily on the monitoring code given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363424(v=vs.85).aspx). This is why I am using an Overlapped method, even though I am only reading data.

The code compiles fine (big whoop, I know) but on running the application hangs when the function is called. I am using [this emulator](http://www.aggsoft.com/com-port-emulator.htm) to send data.

Could someone point out the errors in my work?

UPDATE: 
I tried to isolate the cause of my problem, so I tried to check if the EV_RXCHAR event was being called. I ran the following heavily shortened code:

```
for(;;)
    {
        if(WaitCommEvent(m_hComm,&dwEvtMask,0)) //if 1
        {           
            if(dwEvtMask & EV_RXCHAR) //if 2 
            {
                MessageBox("Data");
                break;
            }
            break;
        }       
       else
          MessageBox("No Data");
       break;
   }//for
```

I am receiving the data, my code to handle the data is horrible. I am starting to work on this.

UPDATE 2: Still working on it, any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `data.GetAt(1)==10||80` does what you wanted it to do? `==` has higher precedence than `||` so it is `(data.GetAt(1)==10) || 80`.

Comment: @GSerg I changed the code to check for just `10`. I will figure out a different expression to check for both. I am sending a message that starts like this : `1010ffffff` and so on for 100 bytes. It still hangs.

Comment: The code is excessively buggy, you'll have to throw it away.  There is no escape from the for(;;) loop so the UI thread will always hang.  Overlapped I/O requires a CreateEvent handle, WaitCommEvent() will always fail.  There is no point in using overlapped I/O when you don't overlap it with useful work.  Casting bytes to LPCTSTR cannot work, it is not a zero-terminated string.  Slapping the user's eyes with 1.7 KB of text every second is not useful.  Use a worker thread to get somewhere, focus on what you are actually going to do with the data.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your input. I understood most of the points you mentioned. Would it be possible for you to explain what you said about the Overlapped I/O required a CreateEvent handle and why WaitCommEvent will always fail? I tried to check if this was returning TRUE, but it wasn't. Also, I have yet to write the code to process this data, so the user won't have to worry about being bombarded with constantly updated data. This was just a trial code to see if I can do serial reading.